# Missing at Random (MAR) vs. Unconfoundedness (conditional exchangeability)

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, missing-data, causality

I thought unconfoundedness is just a special case of MAR under the causal inference framework.

By unconfoundedness $P(A=a|X,Y^{a=0},Y^{a=1})=P(A=a|X)$.

By MAR, $P(A=a|X,Y^{a=0},Y^{a=1})=P(A=a|X,Y^{a})$.

Why does one depends on the observed outcome $Y^{a}$ while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "none of the above". You cannot define confoundedness in terms of traditional conditional probabilities. You must introduce the do operator.

Confounded is best defined in terms of the new causal revolution, with causal diagrams. Consider the following causal diagram (In a causal diagram, we think of $X$ as a cause of $Y$ by having an arrow $X\to Y.$):

[image]

Here, we are thinking of $X$ as a cause of $Y,$ and we want to know if $Z$ is a confounder. It might well be correlated with $X,$ and it certainly shares mutual information with $X.$ However, it is not a confounder, because there is no backdoor path from $X$ to $Y.$ $Z$ is known as a mediator, and there are some very interesting counterfactual methods of handling mediators. See Chapter 4 of *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer*, by Pearl, Glymour, and Jewell. If you want the true causal effect of $X$ on $Y,$ you should NOT control for $Z.$ The equation that shows that $Z$ is not a confounder is this one:

$$P(Y=y|\operatorname{do}(X=x))=P(Y=y|X=x).$$

That is, $X$ and $Y$ are unconfounded if there is no way to distinguish between the *intervention* $\operatorname{do}(X=x)$ and the *observation* $X=x.$

Now consider this causal diagram:

[image]

Now $Z$ is a confounder, because it sets up the backdoor path $X\leftarrow Z\to Y$ from $X$ to $Y.$ In this situation, if you want the true causal effect of $X$ on $Y,$ you must control for $Z.$ You can do the backdoor adjustment formula:
$$P(Y=y|\operatorname{do}(X=x))=\sum_zP(Y=y|X=x,Z=z)\,P(Z=z)$$
to get the true causal effect of $X$ on $Y.$ Here, the expression $\operatorname{do}(X=x)$ means you are setting $X$ equal to $x$ - an intervention that is equivalent to graph surgery: delete all arrows into $X,$ and replace $X$ with $x.$

Comment: I don't quite see why traditional conditional probabilities cannot be used. In one case we condition on the proposition $A :={}$"The quantity $X$ is observed to have value $x$". In the other case we condition on the proposition $B :={}$"The quantity $X$ is set to the value $x$". These are very different propositions, and the conditional probabilities $\mathrm{P}(C | A)$ and $\mathrm{P}(C|B)$ will therefore generally be different for some proposition $C$. We can even consider a proposition such as $B':={}$"The quantity $X$ will be set, in two days, to the value $x$".

Comment: The problem with your proposal is that traditional conditional language in no way can be given the meaning "The quantity $X$ is set to the value $x.$" It is ALWAYS your first: "The quantity $X$ is observed to have value $x.$" Traditional conditionals are observational, not interventional: you cannot FORCE a value.

Comment: Absolutely untrue. The authors who introduced modern conditional notation, Johnson (1924) and especially Keynes (1921) already made very subtle distinctions e.g. between observational, intentional, and even *testimonial* propositions, which the "do"-notation can't capture. All within standard conditional-probability notation. Modern books such as Jaynes's, Lindley's, O'Hagan's, Good's, Hailperin's, also consider these subtle nuances, all with standard notation. The literature, with a long history, on application of probability to courts of law does the same.

Comment: I think you mean that *random-variable* notation is unsuitable, and I agree on that. But it's not the same as probability theory. It's a late dialect meant only for a particular class of circumstances. If you check the books above you'll see they use it only in special situations. Even the do-notation is too limited in more general circumstances (e.g. testimonial evidence, "I set $X$ to $x$" vs "Alice says she set $X$ to $x$"). But the general probability-theory conditional notation has no problem accommodating all possible nuances.

Comment: I think Pearl would disagree with you. The notation $P(Y|X)$ means one thing, and one thing only. Its usage is well-established. See Pearl's books for more. I'm not interested in debating this here.

Comment: One book doesn't decide what's established and what's not. And yes, I'm not interested in dogmatic statements, they aren't part of science, so let's stop the debate. Cheers.